# Buck converter frequency lowers as load current rises (TI TLV62595)

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I simulated a design in the TI Webench tool and I am wondering why the switching frequency falls to 1.2 MHz @ 4 A. Like, where is the point of 2 MHz @ 1 A, when peak current and voltage ripple is the most critical at the highest output current?

My guess would be to reduce switching losses, but with 780 mW they are lower than in other scenarios and not quite near the power dissipation limit.

The datasheet only mentions that there is a power save mode for low currents.

[datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62595.pdf?ts=1707747629059&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252Fde-de%252FTLV62595)

[Webench 4.2 V in, 3 V out, 4 A load](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=CA2DFF5177FF4978)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider these two graphs from the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv62595.pdf?ts=1707747629059&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252Fde-de%252FTLV62595) and work out whether your output voltage might be too close to your input voltage: -

[image]

It's currently impossible to make that call from the data you have provided in your question but, I suspect that this might be the case.

Comment: Thanks. With an output voltage of 3 V and 4 A, the frequency is 1.2 MHz for input voltages under 4.7 V and 2.3 MHz for 4.7 V and up, so this seems to be the reason.
What I do not understand is why it behaves like that and how exactly, as it is not mentioned elsewhere apart from this graph. Is this a general behavior of Buck converters?
These are some graphs from the above example:
The IC current peak exceeds the limit of 4.8 A @4.6V, because it made this step in switching frequency

Comment: [![graph](https://imgur.com/a/dWt9DTG)](https://imgur.com/a/dWt9DTG)

Comment: @GoogleUser as the input voltage gets close to the output voltage, the rate of change of current into the inductor reduces. This means that the energy stored by the inductor in a fixed amount of time is limited and, with a high current on the output, insufficient energy per switching cycle is a distinct possibility so, to mitigate this, the IC lowers its switching frequency in order to get more energy per cycle. This is fundamental to every buck converter ever made and not specific to that IC at all. Laws of inductors and physics basically.

Comment: @GoogleUser If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I can't open those images because the site containing them wants me to stop using my ad blocker and that is something I won't do.

Comment: I don't see the limit here, as the duty cycle is only 65% and this part is capable of 100%. For my understanding, the reduced current ripple which is the same as the delta of inductor energy isn't a requirement, but just the result of lesser difference of input and output.

The essence of the graph is the step of frequency, that I described anyways.

Comment: I have answered your question fully

Comment: If you are aming for a vote, I don't have the ability yet.

Comment: I have said that this is a problem with all buck converters and also answered your formal question. If you did some research on buck converters (or asked a brand-new question), you'd realize that you can't fully transfer the required energy to the output when you raise the duty cycle beyond a certain limit unless you reduce the frequency. It applies to all buck converters.